# U&L Community Promotion Ad on Ask Ubuntu and Stack Exchange trademarks guidelines

Tags: support

I'm mostly active on Ask Ubuntu, and I'd define Ask Ubuntu as my primary community.

However I also often attend U&L, and I wanted to make a Community Promotion Ad for U&L to be shown among the other Ask Ubuntu Community Promotion Ads.

My GIMP skills are very low, however this is what I came up with:

[image: cpa]

[Link to the post on Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14674/380067).

I have a few concerns though:

1. This is technically an unauthorized use of the logo, and alters the original logo's layout. According to the [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

   > Do not use our logo unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Exchange Inc.
   >   Do not distort or alter our logo in any way.

   Do I actually need a permission or otherwise could these rules be walved for an intra-network use of the logo?
2. This is about this community, so I'd like to hear from this community. Are you fine with this alteration of the original logo's layout?

Let me know if anything is wrong with this and I'll take down the post promptly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering only the community aspect, yes I'm fine with rearranging it to be vertical.

You could also steal the layout from the twitter ad, but of course that comes with negative feelings already.

(Also, on a side note, does this ad actually explain to Ask Ubuntu folks why they'd want to come here?)

Comment: Thanks, I waited a bit to see if an answer from a community moderator would have covered the legal aspect; no, it doesn't explain that at all. I thought about rearranging it a bit and add a tagline to the bottom, I think that would look nice, but I'm out of ideas. If you have any suggestion those are of course very welcome (people registered on Ask Ubuntu may as well just comment under the post). Also the ad just scored +6, so it's now officially active and shown between the other ads.